# Append multiple Excel worksheets into one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with 116 sheets that I want to append into one sheet ("Tab_Appended"). I tried the following code and it works. However, column A from the sheets is not pasted to Tab_Appended - where would I have to alter the code to achieve that all data, except the header row, is copied to Tab_Appended?

BTW, I excluded several sheets with 'case' is there a more elegant way to exclude all sheets that contain the string "legend", rather than my listing of all sheets?

```
Sub SummurizeSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRng As Range
    Dim lastCll As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Tab_Appended").Activate

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Set lastRng = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Tab_Appended", "Legende 1", "Legende 2", "Legende 3", "Legende 4", "Legende 5", "Legende 6", "Legende 7", "Legende 8", "Legende 9", "Legende 10", "Legende 11", "Legende 12", "Legende 13"
        'do nothing
        Case Else
            Set lastCll = ws.Columns(1).Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            ws.Range("A2:" & lastCll.Address).Copy
            Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
             'add sheet name before data
            lastRng.Resize(lastCll.Row - 1) = ws.Name
        End Select
    Next ws

    Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete (xlUp)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want col A:B data from all Non legend* sheets into Tab_Appended A:B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have commented the code so that you will not have any problem understanding it.

Regarding your question about ignoring the sheet which have `Legend`; Yes, there is an elegant way and that is using `INSTR`. See below.

What this code is doing is it copies the data from columns from all `Non legend*` sheets into `Tab_Appended` A:M. Hope this is what you wanted? If not then let me know and I will rectify the post.

```
Sub SummurizeSheets()
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsOLr As Long, wsLr As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '~~> Set this to the sheet where the output will be dumped
    Set wsOutput = Sheets("Tab_Appended")

    With wsOutput
        '~~> Get Last Row in "Tab_Appended" in Col A/M and Add 1 to it
        wsOLr = .Range("A:M").Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row + 1

        '~~> Loop through sheet
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            '~~> Check if the sheet name has Legende
            Select Case InStr(1, ws.Name, "Legende", vbTextCompare)

            '~~> If not then
            Case 0
                With ws
                    '~~> Get Last Row in the sheet
                    wsLr = .Range("A:M").Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), _
                           Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

                    '~~> Copy the relevant range
                    .Range("A2:M" & wsLr).Copy wsOutput.Range("A" & wsOLr)

                    '~~> Get Last Row AGAIN in "Tab_Appended" in Col A/B and Add 1 to it
                    wsOLr = wsOutput.Range("A:M").Find(What:="*", After:=wsOutput.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row + 1
                End With
            End Select
        Next
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth! However, I need all columns!

Comment: Do all sheets have the same last column?

Comment: I think it is "M" ? If yes, then refresh the page. I have updated the above code.

Comment: Many thanks - works, except for the header row (that has to be there before calling the subroutine) which is doubled in the end result.. I also found this VBA which does exactly what I want http://www.j-hennekes.de/1115899.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Disappearing column**

There is a strange bit of code in your snippet:

```
Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete (xlUp)
```

So after all sheets contents are copied this line deletes column A, this is not what you want.

Furthermore the code is wrong as deleting a column and then shift up (xlUp) is not possible. You can delete a row maybe and shift it up, or delete a column and shift it left.

As I said this code now makes your column A disappear... Deleting that line will keep your column A from disappearing!

**Using cases**

To exclude certain sheets the use of case is fine, also the way you used it is good enough for a one off. To make it manageable for repetative usage I would suggest to store the list of sheets to exclude in a sheet as you can then drop or add sheet names to that list and dont have to go into the code.

Comment: ..nope - doesn't help. I put the file with the VBA to https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68286640/Append_Tabel.xlsm